# How can I keep my records grouped together using SQL?

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a GAME table with the following fields

match_id, user_id, result

The results always come in pairs with identical match_id.  So for example

```
1837, 4, Win
1837, 29, Forfeit
```

I would like to separate into two groups, one group that has results and one group that doesn't.  This is pretty easily done by using `WHERE result <> ''`

However I've noticed a few strange records such as the following

```
1839, 5, Win
1839, 40,
```

The second record does not have a result recorded against it.  Therefore using `result <> ''` puts splits match 1839 into two separate groups whereas I want them to stay together.  Can I achieve this in SQL?

So basically my pseudo code is:

if both have a result
First group

If either have the result
First group

If none have a result
Second group

Full code using MySQL

```
SQL1: SELECT * from GAME where result <> ''
```

Gives

```
1837, 4, Win
1837, 29, Forfeit
1839, 5, Win


SQL2: SELECT * from GAME where result = ''

1839, 40,
1850, 30,
1850, 5,
```

I'm looking for

SQL1: ??

```
1837, 4, Win
1837, 29, Forfeit
1839, 5, Win
1839, 40,
```

SQL2: ??

```
1850, 30,
1850, 5,
```

Comment: I've amended with the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two ways, depending on the SQL supported by your DBMS.

Using `WHERE ... IN`:

```
SELECT match_id, user_id, result FROM GAME
WHERE match_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT match_id FROM GAME WHERE result <> '' GROUP BY match_id)
GROUP BY match_id
```

Using a derived table:

```
SELECT g.match_id, g.user_id, g.result
FROM GAME AS g INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT match_id FROM GAME WHERE result <> ''  GROUP BY match_id
) AS m ON g.match_id = m.match_id
GROUP BY match_id
```

The idea is the same in both statements, first get the `match_id` from those records that have `result <> ''`, notice the use of `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`, this way you'll get the records for which a `match_id` has a non-blank result.

Then get the info you need for all records that have a `match_id` in the first group of records, that is those records with a `match_id` identified as having a non-blank result.

Answer (score 0):

add 
ORDER BY match_id

to the end of your query.

Comment: This doesn't work because result <> '' splits them into different categories.  I've added pseudo code to my original post to clarify

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will work for your first group:

```
SELECT match_id,user_id,result
FROM GAME G
WHERE
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM GAME WHERE match_id=G.match_id and result <> '')
```

And for the second group:

```
SELECT match_id,user_id,result
FROM GAME G
WHERE
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM GAME WHERE match_id=G.match_id and result <> '')
```

But you should probably look into why there are unmatched records like that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server 2005 or newer:

Try this to for your SQL1:

```
with nonEmptyGames as
(
    SELECT match_id
    FROM Game
    GROUP BY Match_id
    having MAX(Result) != ''
)
SELECT * FROM Games as g
INNER JOIN nonEmptyGames  as neg
ON g.match_id = neg.match_id
```

and this for SQL2:

```
with nonEmptyGames as
(
    SELECT match_id
    FROM Game
    GROUP BY Match_id
    having MAX(Result) != ''
)
SELECT * FROM Games as g
LEFT JOIN nonEmptyGames  as neg
ON g.match_id = neg.match_id
WHERE neg.match_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * from GAME where result <> '' ) as x ORDER BY x.match_id
```

?